# Один из похожих кодов не работает. В чем разница?

Tags: python, строки, циклы

Из строки произвольной длинны нужно вывести все числа.

Этот код работает:

```
print(*(i for i in input() if i.isdigit()), sep="")
```

Этот код не работает:

```
print(i for i in input() if i.isdigit())
```

и выдает

```
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7ff106c5b350>
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем разница между ними, помимо выведения элементов через пробел и разделителя.

Comment: 1. сепаратор на сам факт вывода не влияет. 2. Второй код работает, просто делает не то, что вы думаете. 3. А где вы увидели через пробел?

Comment: *"Один из похожих людей не водитель. В чем разница?"* - странный вопрос. Похожие != идентичные.

Comment: @Эникейщик про пробел хороший вопрос

Answer (score 1):

Звёздочка перед генератором распаковывает значения в генераторе. Без неё вы получаете просто генератор, с которым можно в дальнейшем работать через periodicals или циклами.

```python
arr = ['яблоко', '1', 'мандарин', '12', 'апельсин']

print(*(i for i in arr if i.isdigit()), sep="") ###112

print([i for i in arr if i.isdigit()]) ###['1', '12]

generator = (i for i in arr if i.isdigit())
print(next(generator))
#1
```

Иначе говоря, генераторы — это специальная конструкция, можно вместо них использовать скобки, тогда получится список и дополнительных махинаций в виде звёздочки или `next()` они не требуют.

Генераторы же полезны когда в функцию необходимо передать несколько параметров, можно указать их в списке и передать через звёздочку не расписывая каждый. `print` как раз та самая функция, которая может принимать неограниченное число параметров на вход.

Answer (score 1):

Второй код прекрасно работает. В нём вы передаёте на вход методу `print` генератор и он вам печатает информацию о том, что на вход получен генератор. Питон всегда так делает с объектами, которые он не очень понимает, как ему нужно выводить. Если вы хотите получить **значения**, генерируемые этим генератором, то вам нужно тем или иным образом **проитерироваться** по этому генератору. Например, как это сделано в первом коде - **распаковать** значения из генератора с помощью оператора `*`. Или, например, вот так, с помощью метода `str.join`:

```py
print(''.join(i for i in input() if i.isdigit()))
```